# MAMP - Not Allowed to Load Local Resource

Tags: javascript, mamp

I have an application I'm trying to test but failing to understand why I'm not allowed to do this with MAMP. Pretty much, it's a hub for a bunch of forms that people are able to select one, and it should open on another browser page, but once I put it on MAMP, it will open a new tab, but it will be blank, and give me the error `not allowed to open the local resource` on the browser console (Chrome).

I didn't try any other steps except changing the target on the `window.open` functions to where the files are, instead of using `file:///Directory`.

```
switch (ride) {
        case 1:
            window.open("C:/MAMP/htdocs/File1.html");
            break;
        case 2:
            window.open("C:/MAMP/htdocs/File2.html");
            break;
        case 3:
            window.open("C:/MAMP/htdocs/File3.html");
            break;
        case 4:
            window.open("C:/MAMP/htdocs/File4.html");
            break;
        case 5:
            window.open("C:/MAMP/htdocs/File5.html");
            break;
```

It's just a very simple switch statement calling different locations. Do I have a javascript solution for this, or is this MAMP related?

Thanks

Comment: It's browser security related. There are restrictions on accessing file system directly. If you are running this page at root of htdocs should be able to do `window.open('File1.html')` from page served on your  localhost

Comment: Interesting, because that's what I think I'm doing? I have those files under the folder `htdocs`.

Comment: I think that's what I have but still not working @charlietfl